# How to know which type of HttpEntity returned

Tags: java, apache, http, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache HttpClient API of version 4.3.3.
When I execute the following statement it return HttpResponse instance.

```
HttpResonse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
```

Executed the following statement to get response entity.

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Here I want to know which type of entity object returned. Eg: StringEntity, FileEntity, InputStreamEntity, ...

I tried the following but it returns ResponseEntityWrapper

```
String className = entity.getClass().getName();
```

Is there a way to know the specific type of the response entity ?

Comment: First, convince us that you actually need to know the type of the response entity object.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  I am writing a low level layer for REST call execution. I am planning to return String if the returned response body is StringEntity. If it is FileEntity then I want return Stream.
If I return InputStream for all cases then callers has to code for parsing stream for each use case. If I parse and returns specific response from low level layer, it will reduces the code redundancy at high level layers.

Answer (score 0):

You wont get a Java object straight from the entity, its content is rather something specified by its mime type, which you can get with `entity.getContentType().getValue()` (as long as the content-type is specified, otherwise you would obviously get a NullPointerException).

The content type is a string like "text/plain" or "text/html". For instance, if you get an "application/json" content type, then you need to to use a "deserializer" (like Gson or Jackson) and `entity.getInputStream()` as an input for that deserializer.